# jQuery step by step semi-automated guide in a web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, user-interface, usability

We need to create a feature to help new users understand the product that they are testing during trial period.

We think in creating a jQuery script of semiautomated actions (AKA clics) and popup displaying information. We use a script to enter text in inputs called [Ghostwriter](https://github.com/jharding/ghostwriter) but we need some more features.

Imagine something like when Facebooks delivers a new feature, that makes a step by step introduction in order to show how this works, the ones that you tipically clic the "OK, I get it!" button to skip it.

For some forms we did some scripts displaying tooltips next to fields explaining the usage. But doing this Web Site wide, will create lots of code.

What we need is something more declarative, where you could setup some steps, creating a script in Javascript, that should not polute the existing HTML.

**How should I do this? Any experiences in this kind of issues?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super awesome and easy to use:

[hopscotch](http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/)

Answer (score 1):

I like http://bootstraptour.com/

I'm sure it hits on a lot of features you need.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google search reveals this commercial option: http://www.walkme.com/landing-pages/create-the-ultimate-demo-with-walkme